# Problems with Worksheetfunction.Match in a closed workbook. Cannot work out why no match is found

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I'm writing a code to delete a log entry in a .csv file. The code starts with opening the .csv file, using Application.Match to return the row number, and then deleting that and closing the file again. The problems I'm experiencing are I get a type mismatch (my error handling is activated) OR (and here it gets weird) it works (a match is found, the row is deleted) but then the logfile is messed up - all data is one string in column a with either ";" or "," delimiters (this varies somehow, relevant note: I use Dutch language excel). Of course, this makes it impossible for the macro to find a match in any case.

I found that the type mismatch problems I'm experiencing will most likely be caused by the code not finding a match, and this is what I don't understand since I checked and doublechecked the input and the data in the logfile - by all means it simply should find a match. And sometimes it does find a match, deletes the row and messes up formatting. (NOTE: Mostly it does NOT find a match.)

I check data in the .csv file before running the macro. I have tried running the macro with the .csv file already opened. I have tried to Set the matchArray from outside the With. I have tried both sweet talking my laptop and a more aggressive approach, to no avail.

```vb
Sub DeleteRowFromFile(ByVal matchValue As String)

Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileType As String
Dim matchArray As Range
Dim rowToDelete As Variant

    'Naming variables for flexibility
    filePath = "C:\Users\Maxim\Documents\Log\"
    fileName = "TestRegister"
    fileType = ".csv"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open (filePath & fileName & fileType)

        With Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1)          
            Set matchArray = .Range("A:A") 'set range in the logfile

            'Type mismatch here:
            rowToDelete = Application.Match(matchValue, matchArray, 0)

            If Not IsError(rowToDelete) Then
                Rows(rowToDelete).Delete
            Else:
                MsgBox "Orderno. " & matchValue & " not found.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
            End If

        End With

    'Closing the log file
    Workbooks(fileName).Close SaveChanges:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub MatchAndDelete()
Dim matchValueRange As String

matchValueRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value

DeleteRowFromFile (matchValueRange)

End Sub
```

Footnote:
I'm a struggling enthusiast, I have a lot to learn. Sorry in advance if I have left out any crucial information for you to be of help, and thanks a lot for any and all help.

Comment: You're probably getting a type mismatch error because you're passing a string to `DeleteRowFromFile`, and then you're trying to match it within a range that contains values whose data type are other than strings.  Is this the case?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. I just now tried passing it as a Variant data type. Running the macro then activates the error handling, so I'm assuming all is well but no match was found.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Match it is not required. Try this one.

```
Sub DeleteRowFromFile(ByVal matchValue As String)

Dim filePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim fileType As String
Dim matchArray As Range
Dim rowToDelete As Variant

    'Naming variables for flexibility
    filePath = "C:\Users\Maxim\Documents\Log\"
    fileName = "TestRegister"
    fileType = ".csv"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open (filePath & fileName & fileType)

        With Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1)          
            For i = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
               If .Cells(i, 1).Value2 = matchValue Then
                   .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next

        End With

    'Closing the log file


    Workbooks(fileName & fileType).SaveAs Filename:= _
    (filePath & fileName & fileType) _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False 'Saving the file
    Workbooks(fileName & fileType).Close 'Closing the file 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This works, good thinking. But, unfortunately after this process the formatting of the .csv file is changed. All data (previously separated in columns) is moved to column "A" and seperated by delimiter ",". This happened before and I think I read somewhere that this can happen when VBA (which uses "," delimiters) edits a file in my Dutch version Excel (which uses ";" delimiters). But, it also happened that the formatting changed in the same way, but seperated by ";", and so I don't know why Excel doesn't auto-format this to seperate columns. Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Comment: Coukd you send me one sample? I will fix it. Recently I fixed one similar problem on RINEX files.

Comment: For example, this is data from one row:
` 1006,Testwerk 1,Testwerk 2,Testwerk 3,Testwerk 4,Testwerk 5,Testwerk 6,Testwerk 7,Testwerk 8,Testwerk 9,Testwerk 10,Omschrijving 1,Omschrijving 2,Omschrijving 3,Omschrijving 4,Omschrijving 5,Omschrijving 6,Omschrijving 7,Omschrijving 8,Omschrijving 9,Omschrijving 10,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,0,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,0,Uitgave 1,Uitgave 2,Uitgave 3,Uitgave 4,Uitgave 5,Beschrijving 1,Beschrijving 2`
All this used to be in seperate columns, now it's all in one cell, column A

Comment: It is basically back to how it was printed into the file, only now with "," in stead of ";" to divide the data.

Comment: I already change the code to keep the format and all the information in one column with no spacers. You should save it as CSV(MS-DOS)

Answer (score 0):

When you open or save a csv file using a VBA macro Excel will always use the standard (US English delimiters) while if you do the same via the user interface it will use the separators as defined in the Windows regional settings, which probably is ";" in your case.
You can check with `.?application.International(xlListSeparator)` in the immediate window of your VBEditor.

You can tell Excel to use a different separator, by e.g. adding `sep=;` as line 1 of your file. Hoever this entry is gone after opening the file. The following code - added before you open the csv file will add this:

```
Dim oFSo As Object
Dim oTxtFile As Object
Dim strData As String

Set oFSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strData = oFSo.OpenTextFile(filePath & fileName & fileType, 1).ReadAll

Set oTxtFile = oFSo.OpenTextFile(filePath & fileName & fileType, 2)

oTxtFile.writeline "sep=;"
oTxtFile.writeline strData

oTxtFile.Close
```

You can save your changed file by using the Excel UserInterface Shortcuts via the `Application.SendKeys` thus achieving what you want:

```
Application.SendKeys ("^s")             'Save
Application.SendKeys ("^{F4}")          'Close
```

Dont run this code from the VBE Immeditate window as it will probabaly act on the wrong file!

The full code - just with an alternate way to make the requested change:

```
Sub DeleteRowFromFile(ByVal matchValue As String)

    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileType As String
    Dim matchArray As Range
    Dim rowToDelete As Variant
    Dim oFSo As Object
    Dim oTxtFile As Object
    Dim strData As String
    Dim content As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'Naming variables for flexibility
    filePath = "C:\Users\Maxim\Documents\Log\"
    fileName = "TestRegister"
    fileType = ".csv"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    'Adding "sep =" ; as line 1 of the log file
    Set oFSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    strData = oFSo.OpenTextFile(filePath & fileName & fileType, 1).ReadAll

    Set oTxtFile = oFSo.OpenTextFile(filePath & fileName & fileType, 2)

    oTxtFile.writeline "sep=;"
    oTxtFile.writeline strData

    oTxtFile.Close

    'Open logfile
    Workbooks.Open (filePath & fileName & fileType)

    'Make your changes
    With Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(1)
        content = .UsedRange.Value
        For i = UBound(content, 1) To 1 Step -1
           If content(i, 1) = matchValue Then
               .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    'Closing the log file via Sendkeys using excel shortcuts
    Application.SendKeys ("^s")             'Save
    Application.SendKeys ("^{F4}")          'Close

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```